# AWS Step Function Task Token Prior To Wait

Tags: aws-step-functions

Good Morning Everyone,

I am trying to manage some async actions via the step function but I need to be able to send and receive the token during separate phases. I have been looking at the documentation and it seems like this isn't possible as the await token is only a specific task within a step function and can't be created ahead of time.

Is this setup possible or do I need to restructure to accommodate the restriction of a task token is specific to a task (ie. I would have to await on the send of the data even tho that isn't the process that will receive the data)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you say, "[Callback tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html) provide a way to pause a workflow until a task token is returned."  But you don't want to wait.  If I understand right, you want to fire off the job to the 3rd Party
do some more work in your Step function, and only then wait for the processed results.

How about this orchestration, which does not make use of tokens:

`Lambda-1 (SFN) -> 3rd Party -> Lambda-2 -> SQS Queue`:  Lambda-1 sends a request to the 3rd Party, which completes its work and it passes the response to Lamba-2.  Lambda-2 puts its result into a Queue. The only change here is SQS at the end.

You Step Function looks like:

1. Lambda-1 sends data to 3rd Party - no .callback, just fire off the request and return
2. (Do more work in the Step Function)
3. [Poll the Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) for a Result, using the newly introduced [AWS SDK service integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html).
4. If no result, [wait and repeat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-job-poller.html#sample-project-job-poller-create) up to 10 minutes, periodically repolling the queue.
5. Lambda-3 and Lambda-4 if success or failure

Using a queue in this way robustly lets either branch (Lambda-2 or More-Work) to finish earlier.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the confirmation. AWS documentation has a lot to be desired and I was hoping someone might have known of a way to setup a token ahead of time and wait on that token later.